# What's the equivalent function in KissFFT for fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d() from FFTW?

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, fftw, kissfft

I've got a project that uses `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` and `fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d` from FFTW, as well as `fftw_execute`. What are the equivalent functions in KissFFT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the real-optimised functions in kiss_fftr.h (in the `tools` subdirectory). Use `kiss_fftr_alloc` instead of setting up FFTW "plans" with `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` and `fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d`. Use `kiss_fftr` and `kiss_fftri` to do the forward/inverse transforms instead of calling FFTW's `fftw_execute`. Don't forget to call `kiss_fftr_free` when you're done.